# Best software for creating free Infographics

Tags: software-recommendation, information-graphics

I use Illustrator to create custom infographics, but was looking for a service that could create them faster as my company is looking to do multiple infographics per month. I enjoy doing Infographics, but they take some time and would like to focus on other things rather than making Infographics all day.

I've heard of Piktochart, but was wondering if anybody had any other recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

### **[Easel.ly](http://www.easel.ly/)**

- How easy is this tool? The name suggests it.
- It's free? Yes.
- Can I import my own graphics? Yes.
- Any more alternatives? Yes, [visual.ly](http://visual.ly/), [Infogr.am](http://infogr.am/).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a website which shows top 10 infographics tools

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-of-the-best-tools-for-creating-infographics/

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer to give details about that link??  At this time your answer is a link only answer and that is frowned upon on this community.  Furthermore, if the link were to go down your answer will be deleted because it will serve no purpose.